# How to prevent travis jobs after each commit?

Tags: github, travis-ci

I am developing a library on github that has travis checks attached to it. I'd like to have a WIP pull request open to discuss ideas easily. There is a lot of tests set up for the project on travis, so I'd like to not trigger the tests every time I push a commit (to prevent server for being overloaded), as the code is not expected to pass anyway.

Is there a way I could do this on github without having access to travis configuration?

Comment: You can add `[ci skip]` to your commit messages or immediately `exit` if `$TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST == "false"`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To skip builds on a per-commit basis you can add `[ci skip]` to the commit message, as described in the [Docs](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/#Skipping-a-build), for example:

Before: `Add blerb`.
After:
`Add blerb
[ci skip]`

To skip *all* non-PR builds, you can early-exit if the [`TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST` environnment variable is set to `"false"`](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables#Convenience-Variables) fron your `.travis.yml`:

```
before_install:  # Earliest build step
  - if [ "$TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST" == "false" ]; then echo "Not a PR, skipping" && exit; fi
```

Answer (score 1):

My approach is to use an alias that I defined that appends the `[ci skip]` to each commit message of the current branch.

```
wip = "!f() { git filter-branch -f --msg-filter 'sed -e "\"s/$/ \\[ci skip\\]/g\""' ${1-master}..HEAD ; }; f"
unwip = "!f() { git filter-branch -f --msg-filter 'sed -e "\"s/ \\[ci skip\\]//g\""' ${1-master}..HEAD ; }; f"
wpush = "!f() { git wip $1 && git fpush && git unwip $1 ; }; f"
```

So basically what I do is simply `git wpush`.